# How to create a bar chart like shown in the image in android showing the time in seconds minutes and hour format?

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

[image][image]

How to create such type of bar chart in android application, here the data are being formatted and are in the form of seconds, mins and hours

Comment: Use MPChartLibaray - https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: Yes I did used that but how can I show all these datas on the chart I mean the data can be in hr, min and seconds..And that also without the Y axis...

Comment: Yes I did used that but how can I show all these datas on the chart I mean the data can be in hr, min and seconds..And that also without the Y axis... @Shane

Comment: You have to convert date to your preferred timestamp format

Comment: How can you please help me out I am stuck on this .. thing...@Shane

Comment: Share your data to build this graph.

Comment: Seconds   Date
3600       2019-11-12
3             2019-11-13
4             2019-11-13
10           2019-11-13
11           2019-11-13
4500       2019-11-14

Comment: I have attached the screenshot the data are in the database and there are two columns ie. start date and time and end date and time and I am finding the difference between the two to get the time which can be 2 seconds, 4 mins or 5 hours and need to display that on the graph...

Comment: I have attached the screenshot the data are in the database and there are two columns ie. start date and time and end date and time and I am finding the difference between the two to get the time which can be 2 seconds, 4 mins or 5 hours and need to display that on the graph.. @Shane

Comment: You have time in millisecond right?

Comment: Yes they are in seconds...I was getting them in milli and then I converted it to seconds..

Comment: Ok, then you can counts minutes or hours from that.

Comment: okay but the chart will take the float as input na...

Comment: okay but the chart will take the float as input na...@iDroid

Comment: I don't have more idea but i think this can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42320954/9792247

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202797/discussion-between-idroid-and-pooja-pachchigar).